# In Maze which have N keys what should i do to find shortest path with BFS?

Tags: python, algorithm

Now, I'm trying to implement finding shortest path program with Python
In my case, Maze has N keys and i should find all keys to escape from Maze

Example) start Point S, Key1 , Key2, Finish point F
We have 2 paths

1. S -> Key1 -> Key2 -> F
2. S -> Key2 -> Key1 -> F

If it has 3 Keys then, it becomes hard

1. S-> Key1 -> Key2 ->Key3 ->F
2. S-> Key1 -> Key3 ->Key2 ->F
3. S-> Key2 -> Key3 ->Key1 ->F
4. S-> Key2 -> Key1 ->Key3 ->F
5. S-> Key3 -> Key1 ->Key2 ->F
6. S-> Key3 -> Key2 ->Key1 ->F

Anyway, To solve this, I make each visit matrix to get all distances From Each node(S,F,Key)
But, I don't know what should I do from now on.

**Please Help Me
How can I get shortest path in this case?**

Comment: Have you looked into Permutation and Combination? Maybe they might help.
[here is the documentations](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/itertools.html?highlight=combinations#itertools.permutations) Not sure if you are looking for this.

Comment: This is an adaptation of the TSP (see [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem) for more info). The only difference is that S and F are separated, but we only have to add the F ► S path to be in the same situation.